# MongoDB Ops manager admin user & normal user account getting locked often

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replicaset

I am using MongoDB Opsmanager Application with MongoDB replica set as Application Database for it.

**Issue:**

1.Often Admin account gets locked

2.Rarely normal user account gets locked

Error : Your account is locked. Please contact your admin to unlock your account

**Current Temp Solution:**

1.Connect the Mongo Ops Manager Application DB using Mongo Shell

2.Run below command

```
 use mmsdbconfig


 db.config.users.update({"un": ""}, {$set: {"isLocked": false, lastPageView: new Date()}})
```

I want to find the permanent solution and reason for this

Comment: Check server logs.

Comment: @D.SM  No clear reason in logs